# Estimators and confidence interval

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

Can someone explain me how to solve the following exercise? 
I don't like to post this kind of question, but in this case I have a really bad theory material and I would greatly appreciate a concrete example.

Given the following sample:
S = {40, 80, 40, 60, 0, 40, 20, 40, 60, 100}

1. Calculate an estimator of parameter μ of the underlying Poisson variable
2. Calculate an estimator of parameter λ of the underlying negative exponential variable
3. Give a confidence interval with confidence level 0.9 of both parameters

**My attempts**

1. The underlying Poisson distribution must be coherent with the sample (i.e. the sample average must be equal to the Poisson distribution expected value). $μ=\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{x\in S}x=\frac{40+80+40+60+0+40+20+40+60+100}{10}=48$
2. Given a random variable $X \sim Exponential(λ)$, we have $μ=E[X]=\frac{1}{λ}$, from which we get $λ=\frac{1}{μ}=\frac{1}{48}$
3. ???

Comment: For estimation of the mean, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Parameter_estimation).

Comment: The only way I know how to compute confidence intervals is from a Monte Carlo simulation where you choose n random samples from the underlying distribution and compute the estimation and then give a confidence interval? Or maybe they want to have variance of the estimator? Either way I am keen to see myself if what I said is not what you are looking for :).

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate the confidence interval for $\lambda$ using a chi-squared distribution. Check this article on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Confidence_interval.